# Upload Multiple Files With media_handle_upload does not work

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a problem uploading images to the product gallery, when I add files to upload, it works, and if I leave the upload field empty, it gives an error, how do I make a check so that I can not attach images?

```
// Upload Images Gallery

 if ( $_FILES ) {
    $files = $_FILES['file'];
  foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) { 
                  if ($files['name'][$key]) { 
  
                      $file = array( 
                          'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                          'type' => $files['type'][$key], 
                          'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key], 
                          'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                          'size' => $files['size'][$key]
                      ); 
                      $_FILES = array ("file" => $file);
                      $newupload = my_handle_attachment( "file", $post_id);
                 
                    }    
      
              $attach_newupload_ids[]=$newupload;//I think the value check needs to be done here
          }

          $attach_ids=implode(',',$attach_newupload_ids);
          if($attach_ids){
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $attach_ids);
          }  
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_FILES['file']['error'] == 4 is means that no file was uploaded, I think that you can use something like.

```
if($_FILES['file']['error'] == 4){
echo "no file was uploaded";
}else{
echo "file was uploaded";
}
```

after some comments with @Andrey this work fine for his code

```
if ($newupload = 0) {
  $attach_newupload_ids[] = 4;
}else{
  $attach_newupload_ids[] = $newupload;
}
```

Comment: @AndreyMiller, my another opinion is you must add if else statement in here if($attach_ids){ update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $attach_ids); } else{ update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_image_gallery', 0); } and then edit your update_post_meta function to ignore images that why I add 0

Comment: @AndreyMiller, I edit my answer, if you wanna you can accept the answer "the half answer is yours" :-))) Thank you